# Creating a dynamic search box/table in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter

What I'm trying to achieve is a `JTextField` with a `JTable` on the bottom, every time a change occurs on the `JTextField` (type or delete a character) the `JTable` would update showing the results from it's list of strings that match what is written on the `JTextField`, and showing all results if empty.

What I don't know how to do :

1. How to set the event on the JTextField that triggers everytime its text changes
2. Making the JTable update its values in an efficient way, without using too much memory

Comment: 1.Use a KeyListener on the JTextField.
2.This depends on what algorithm you're using to identify matching strings.

Comment: It's a very simple school project, probably just String.matches(s) or String.indexOf(s)

Comment: In your last question you stated you read the Oracle tutorial on GridBagLayout. Well, I suggest you also read the section on `How to Use Tables` from the same tutorial. It shows how to use a filter on the JTable that does exactly what you want. The tutorial (not the forum) should be the first place to start for Swing basics.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) to your `JTextField`. Update the [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) belonging to your `JTable` with matches. The `JTable` will update itself in  response.

Comment: @Mojimi read Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables [for working code example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java)